# $\lim_{x\to 0^+}[1+[x]]^{2/x}$,where [x] denotes greatest integer function less than or equal to x

Tags: limits

Find the value of $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}[1+[x]]^{\frac2x}$$where $[x]$ denotes greatest integer function less than or equal to $x$.

---

**My attempt:** 
I calculated $[1+[x]]$ to be $1$ as $x\to 0^+$. 
 Now I am stuck. 
 Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if $f(x)\to 1$ and $g(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to0$ then $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{\lim_{x\to0}g(x)(f(x)-1)}$.

Here $f(x)=1+[x]\to1$ and $g(x)=2/x\to\infty$ as $x\to0+$. Thus the limit is $e^{\lim_{x\to0+}(2/x)[x]}$

Now as $x$ goes to $0$, $x<1$ must be true after some stage. Then for all such $x$, $[x]=0$ so $\lim_{x\to0+}\dfrac{[x]}{x}=0$.

So the answer is $e^0=1$.

Comment: I think it would be $e^2$.

Answer (score 2):

For $0<x\ll 1$, $[1+[x]] = 1$. Thus $[1+[x]]^{2/x} = 1^{2/x} = 1$.This gives 
$$ \lim_{x→ 0^+}[1+[x]]^{2/x} = \lim_{x→ 0^+} 1 = 1$$

Answer (score -1):

Substitute $y=\frac1x$, so as $x\to0^{+}, y\to\infty$. 
So we get $$\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}[1+[\frac{1}{y}]]^{2y}=\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}([1+[\frac1y]]^{y})^2=1^{2.\infty}=1$$

Comment: This is incorrect because you ignored the "next lower integer" function.  Once $y$ gets bigger than 1, $[\frac1y]$ will be $0$.

Comment: Oh sorry, please see the edit.